# Set value for key of a single NSMutableDictionary from an array of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

While trying to set a single key/value pair in NSMutableDictionary of NSMutableArray like:

```
[[self.items objectAtIndex:i] setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

`self.items` is `NSMutableArray` and it have a list of NSMutableDictionaries

Instead of setting to that single object, it set it to all dictionaries in the list.

I have used this method before. But I don't know what is happening in this case.

I know `NSArray` have  `setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key` method, but in this case I am using NSMutableArray

Here is a bit more block of code to help clarify my situation:

```
-(void)setItem:(id)sender
{ 
    for (CellView *cell in self.CollectionView.visibleCells)
    {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.CollectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
        int i = (indexPath.section * (mainItems.count)/3+ indexPath.row);

        if (((UIButton *)sender).tag == i)
        {
                [[self.items objectAtIndex:i] setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: verify that `[self.items objectAtIndex:i]` is really returning a dictionary

Comment: if objectAtIndex:i is a mutable dict and value will never be nil, then you should use setObject:forValue: There are lots of other things that setValue will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`. There is a difference.

Note that `NSMutableArray` extends `NSArray` so `NSMutableArray` has all of the methods of `NSArray`.

I also recommend you split your line up as well as use modern syntax:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = self.items[i];
dict[@"key"] =  @"value";
```

Comment: thanks for the other comments, but `setObject:forKey:` also set it to all objects in the list

Comment: No, `setObject:forKey:` did not set all objects in the list. It will only change one value in the one dictionary. I suggest you update your question with a little more code so we can see what you are really doing.

Comment: ya, I have replaced that with `setObject:forKey:` and checked it also. It is the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray` so all the `NSArray` methods are still there in `NSMutatbleArray`. You could try pulling it out and putting it back in to figure things out then reassemble your code after...

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [self.items objectAtIndex:i];
[d setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
[self.items setObject: d atIndexedSubscript: i];
```

This is a little more explicit which will allow you to debug it easier (not getting unexpected **nils** back, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the issue.

I am working on a large pre-existing code. And I come to notice that The `MutableDictionary` was defined globally and the same object was being added to the `MutableArray`. So basically all the pointers in the `MUtableArray` where pointing to a single object.